# Как эти коммиты просмотреть в папке в пхп шторме по порядку?

Tags: php, git, phpstorm, git-commit

```
https://github.com/ElisDN/php-demo-psr7-framework/commits/master
```

Как эти коммиты просмотреть в папке в PhpStorm по порядку?
Чтобы листать на компьютере

Comment: Склонировать себе репозиторий и смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Создайте в phpstorm новый проект "get from Version control" и используя функционал version control в phpstorm просматривайте.